# Access a while looped variable from a function that is running in thread and use in other function in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop

I am working on a complex project that is related to threading. Here is the simplest interpretation of my problem. Below is the code here are 3 functions excluding the main function. All functions are running in multi-threads. There is a while loop in all functions. I just want to get variable "i" and "k" from "func1" and "func2" respectively and use it in "func3". These variables are updated in the while loop.
This is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Threading
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void func1() //How can I get the variable "i" from the while loop. Note: This function is running in thread.
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Func1: " + i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        public static void func2() //How can I get the variable "k" from the while loop. Note: This function is running in thread.
        {
            int k = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Func2: " + k);
                k++;
            }
        }

        public static void func3() //After getting variables from func1 and func2 I want them to use in function 3.
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int sum = i + k;
                Console.WriteLine("the sum is" + sum);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(func1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(func2);
            Thread t3 = new Thread(func3);
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the `func3` should display repeatedly the sum of `i` an `k`, while the `func1` and `func2` are running?

Comment: Yes exactly. All functions should run concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to hoist the `i` and `k` from local variables to private fields of the `Program` class. Since these two fields will be accessed by more than one threads without synchronization, you should also declare them as [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile):

```
private static volatile int i = 1;
private static volatile int k = 1;

public static void func1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Func1: " + i);
        i++;
    }
}

public static void func2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Func2: " + k);
        k++;
    }
}

public static void func3()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int sum = i + k;
        Console.WriteLine("the sum is" + sum);
    }
}
```

The pattern of access makes the use of `volatile` a bit wasteful though. The `func1` is the only method that changes the `i`, so reading it with volatile semantics inside this method is pure overhead. You could use instead the [`Volatile.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read) and [`Volatile.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.write) methods for finer control:

```
private static int i = 1;
private static int k = 1;

public static void func1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Func1: " + i);
        Volatile.Write(ref i, i + 1);
    }
}

public static void func2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Func2: " + k);
        Volatile.Write(ref k, k + 1);
    }
}

public static void func3()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int sum = Volatile.Read(ref i) + Volatile.Read(ref k);
        Console.WriteLine("the sum is" + sum);
    }
}
```